# Remove directory if they contain element from list

Tags: python, loops, directory

I have directory called 'data' that contains the subfolders: sub-001, sub-002, sub-003,  sub-004,  sub-005,  sub-006, etc.

The number intuitively indicates the subject number, and I have a list specifying the subjects to exclude in my analysis. The exclude list looks like this:

exclude = ['001','003','006']

I want to make a script that removes all the directories that contains the elements specified in the list (i.e., sub-001, sub-003 and sub-006). I have backup data, so completely deleting the directory is not an issue. All the sub-00x directories contain subfolders which should also be removed.

Hope that someone can help :)

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Iterating over the directories? Deleting a directory? What code do you have till now?

Comment: What is the specific problem you have and what have you tried to solve it (show properly formatted code in the question)?

Comment: You can use `glob` for creating a list of directories, a `for` loop for going over them and checking them against every item in your `exclude` list, and use `shutil.rmtree()` to recursively delete that directory.

Answer (score 0):

This question need for details to answer, and is most likely not a good question. Anyway, here is the code I believe you're looking for:

```
import os


excludes = ['001', '003', '006']

subdirs = [f.path for f in os.scandir(os.getcwd()) if f.is_dir()]
for subdir in subdirs:
    for exclude in excludes:
        if exclude in subdir:
            os.rmdir(subdir)
```